# Updating from Babel to version 7 having issues with browserify

Tags: gulp, browserify, babeljs

I'm trying to update my version of babel from 6 to 7, I've uninstalled babel 6 making the following changes to my package.json file ti update to version 7 and update browserify and babelify to be able to handle the babel update.

```
-    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
-    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-for-of": "^6.23.0",
-    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
-    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
-    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
-    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
-    "babelify": "^8.0.0",
-    "browserify": "^16.2.0",
+    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
+    "@babel/plugin-transform-for-of": "^7.2.0",
+    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.2.0",
+    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
+    "babelify": "^10.0.0",
+    "browserify": "^16.2.3",
```

I have a simple implementation of gulp that looks as follows:

```
gulp.task('js:compile', ['js:lint'], function () {
    return browserify({
        entries: paths.js + '/main.js',
        debug: true
    })
    .transform(babelify, { global: true })
    .bundle()
    .on('error', function (err) { console.error(err); })
    .pipe(source('main.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.buildJs));
});
```

And my .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
        "@babel/preset-env", {
            "modules": false,
            "targets": {
                "browsers": [
                    "last 5 versions",
                    "ie 11",
                    "safari >= 7"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-for-of",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

When I try and run this I get the following error, main.js being the main entry point for my javascript.

`SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (1:0) while parsing /Users/codecomp/test/assets/js/main.js while
parsing file: /Users/codecomp/test/assets/js/main.js`

This implementation worked fine previously with my older versions of Babel, Browserify and Babelify/ I've been digging through the change-logs and I can't find anything relevant that would have caused the issue. I had the same error previously when I first set the project up, though I can't recall what I had fixed it or caused it.

Comment: Shouldn't you pass babel's preset into babelify? like `.transform("babelify", {presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]})`, though i'm not sure if that'll help since you said it worked with babel 6 also 

Comment: I forgot to add my babelrc file to the post